# How can I get the StartDate and endDate from a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table. I would like to see the result by startdate and enddate. The bottom image is output. I want output in that format:

[image: This is my data]

[image: I want result in this manner. I want startdate and enddate for each payermode]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PayerMode](
    [Location] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Customer] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [PayMode] Varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/20/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/21/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/22/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/23/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/24/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/25/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/26/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/27/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/28/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/29/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/30/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/31/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '4/1/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/20/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/21/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/22/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/23/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/24/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/25/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/26/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/27/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/28/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/29/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/30/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/31/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '4/1/2014','Credit');
```

Now, I am seeing that there is a gap in my dataset. How can I achieve the same result. when there is a gap then the above query is not working. Here is my new dataset and I want the same result with StartDate and EndDate.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PayerMode](
    [Location] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Customer] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [PayMode] Varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/20/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/21/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/22/2014','Insurance');

INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/25/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/26/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/27/2014','Insurance');

INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/29/2014','Cash');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/30/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '3/31/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45454, '4/1/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/20/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/21/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/22/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/23/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/24/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/27/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/28/2014','Insurance');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '3/31/2014','Credit');
INSERT INTO PayerMode VALUES (100, 45678, '4/1/2014','Credit');
```

I want result like this.

```
Location customer StartDate enddate     paymode
100      45454    3/20/2014  3/22/2014  Insurance
100      45454    3/25/2014  3/27/2014  Insurance
100      45454    3/29/2014  3/29/2014  Cash
```

Comment: Please add your sample data as insert / select statements that we can easily use to test.

Comment: I have given you a sample dataset. I added an image. It was not allowing me to add sample table. Do you want insert statements?  I want each customer's startDate and enddate for each paytype. this is a sequence of a table with dates. I just want min and max date for each range by paymode.

Comment: _Do you want insert statements_ Would be nice, or would you like us to type in all your data in order to provide a solution? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  This version is probably most simply solved using the difference of row numbers:

```
select location, customer, paymode, min(date), max(date)
from (select pm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location, customer order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by location, customer, paymode order by date) as seqnum_2
      from payermode pm
     ) pm
group by (seqnum - seqnum_2), location, customer, paymode
order by location, customer, min(date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6cc288a684dd9db3c02a1148e15df50) is a db<>fiddle.

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference of row numbers identifies adjacent rows with the same value.

EDIT:

If you want consecutive dates to be combined, the problem is even simpler:

```
select location, customer, paymode, min(date), max(date)
from (select pm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location, customer, paymode order by date) as seqnum
      from payermode pm
     ) pm
group by dateadd(day, -seqnum, date), location, customer, paymode
order by location, customer, min(date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4fe42698d43c7bb947e8769d7c502a1) is a db<>fiddle for this version.

Comment: Hi, I tested it but I found that there is a gap on the dates. Here is my new dataset.

Comment: Can you take a look at my new dataset? I have a gap in the dates. hence the above query is not working. It is calculating the min and the max date.

Comment: That actual *simplifies* the query.  I added an answer for that version as well.